# How to ping/ssh to a system that is connected to a router

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, ssh, ping

Let us say I have system A and system B. I would like to ping system A from system B. But, system A is connected to a router, the router is connected to the base network. System B is connected directly to the same base network via wifi (either directly or through VPN). Now, how do I ping system A from system B.

I need to know the IP address of A in the base network, so I can ping. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

(I'm on ubuntu if that helps)

Comment: If they are part of the same subnet you just ping the other device.  What have you tried? Intranet addresses only exist within your network, so the more detailed you are in your description, the easier it will be determine what you are doing incorrectly

Comment: Could you tell me what other details would be necessary? I will provide them. I'm fairly new to this, so I'm not sure what details are relevant. thanks! To your comment, since system B is on a router, is it not on a different network from A?

Comment: Is this a NAT based router?  Are both devices on the same vlan, or is one on the WAN and one on the NATed LAN?  Do you have the IP for the system you are trying to ping, or are you asking how you can get it?

Comment: You don't provide any specifics. If Machine A is connected to the router through an Ethernet connection, and Machine B is connected to the same router through a Wireless connection, then both machines are connected to the same network.  You don't tell us what error you received when you attempted to make the connection.  Most of your information is pretty generic which makes your problem you face extremely dfficult to diagnose.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know the IP address of A in the base network, so I can ping.

If it doesn't have an `IP in the base network`, it doesn't. It doesn't have to anyway, even regardless of whether it's behind NAT. If you want to know the IP of A, just check on A, end of story. (Well, you might be able to check on `router` as well, by looking up its ARP table / DHCP client list.)

(Certainly I'm not talking about the "apparent IP" of it when traffics from / to it flow through base network. *That* IP would probably be the WAN IP of `router` in this case, which in turn should be an "IP in the base network", if the traffics are NAT'd. The IP simply isn't relevant to your question, at least not in the way you might have thought. See below.)

The fact that A is connected to a `router` essentially means that it won't be in the same *broadcast domain* as B / `the base network` and will normally be under a different IP subnet, because that's the definition of a `router` -- a device that *forwards* traffics on IP layer for / *across* two or more networks / broadcast domains.

(Certainly though, it's possible that the `router`, assuming that you are talking about typical consumer-grade / home router, has been interconnected / configured to work as a simple *switch*. However I don't suppose that is your case otherwise you probably won't be asking the question here.)

The real key to your question is route -- whether on B there's an indirect route that routes traffics destined at A('s IP configured for `router`'s LAN), with the WAN IP of `router` being the gateway / nexthop. Theoretically once you added the route, you should be able to initiate communication with A from B. (In reality, the firewall on `router`, if any, might block such traffics. Also some, *but not all*, NAT implementation might twist things up. For example, NAT in the Linux / netfilter is *stateful*.)

When B doesn't have the required route, traffics destined at A's IP would likely be routed *via* B's default gateway (e.g. another router that interconnects base network and some other network like the Internet) instead. When the gateway doesn't have the required route either, the traffics would be in turn routed *via* *its* default gateway (which is out of the scope of the story here).

I have no idea what kind of VPN you are talking about though. If you are talking about some L2 VPN, what I just mentioned will probably hold. However if you are talking about some L3 VPN, the VPN server will instead need to have the route, as there's no such thing as indirect route in L3 VPN. (And adding the route on the default gateway of B instead of B itself should likely do for the physically connected case as well, albeit less ideal.)